# PowerDesigner Internal Database - Relating Entities to Diagrams

Tags: powerdesigner

I am tring to write some ETL to extract Conceptual Models, and their assoicated Diagrams and Entities, out of a powerdesigner database.

So Far, I have the querys that return:

1/ The list of Conceptual Models (based on the class name 'Conceptual Data Model').

2/ The list of Conceptual Diagrams assoicated with each Conceptual Model (based on the data in 1/ and the relationship class 'Diagrams' to the targe object class 'Conceptual Diagram').

3/ The list of entities associated with each Conceptual Model (based on the data in 1/ and the relationship class 'Entities' to the targe object class 'Entity').

My problem is that I need to understand the set of Entities, 3/ above, assoicated with each Diagram, 2/ above. There are no records in the relationship table, PMRLSH, for these.

TL;DR Does anyone know where in the powerdesigner database the set of entities contained in a conceptual diagram are stored?

Answer (score 1):

This information is not directly available.

All the diagram contents (including the references toward displayed design objects) is packed as the long text (in PMTEXT, in an undocumented format) indicated by PMOBJT.BCOL.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had a look and just to clarify it is a binary and is stored in PMLBIN rather than PMTEXT. Of course knowing the table doesn't really help me as there doesn't appear to be a way to interrogate the binary.